# Switch Networks automatically when wifi is down

Tags: linux

I have two networks which go down sometimes. Someone made me this command to switch when there is no ping from google.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
chk()
{
    ping -c 1 -t 116 www.google.com
    if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]
    then
        nmcli con up uuid <network>
    fi
    sleep 60
    chk
 }
```

When I run this with a good connection it works. But when there is no connection it will say network unreachable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://askubuntu.com/questions/481165/automatic-switch-between-the-wifi-and-ethernet-in-linux-using-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
nmcli connect modify 'conname' connection.autoconnect yes
```

shell scripts use

```
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
else; nmcli con up conname ; fi
```

case `connect: Network is unreachable`
`echo $?` result is May not be 1.

Only 0 is output for a successful connection